# Method when called in another class, the value of the variable is not updated in C#

Tags: c#

I have a method in which a boolean is updated to "True". I have another method whose return type is also boolean and the same variable name, but the value is not updated.

```
public bool fault=false;

public void add()
{
    fault=true;
}

public bool sub()
{
    return fault;
}
```

The method `sub()` is to be called in another class and over there it is not updated. The `add()` method is always called before `sub()`
Both the methods are in different projects. The project in which method sub() is, is dependent on the project in which the method add() is.

Comment: Fix your code formatting, and post a working example that showcases your issue please. This will not be enough for anyone to go off of.

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the "add" method before calling the "sub" method, otherwise you bool value will not be "true".  But please post a working example of your code so we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: If sub() is called in another class, it's not impossible to think that it's being called before add(), which is why 'fault' is never set to true.

Comment: It is always called before sub()

Comment: Can you show how it is used in the method that calls `sub`?

Comment: What do you mean by it is not updated

Comment: Is it possible that the methods `add` and `sub` are called on different instances of the class?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary The value is not updated to "true" it stays as the initial value "false"

Comment: I think you should post a complete example showing your problem. The code you posted would work, it's the calling code that is the problem.

Comment: @MariumMalik - please show ALL the relevant code. The code you have shown so far  will work.

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint in `add()`, and make sure fault gets updated.

Then right click the `fault`variable, and select *Make Object ID*. put also a breakpoint in `sub()` and make an object ID on fault again (if it isn't already there).

Make sure the object ID is the same, if it is not: ( #1 and #2 ) your instance of fault is not the same. Most likely because the method is not called on the same instance.

You then have a choice: either you make fault static, or you only keep one instance of your class.

Comment: When I right click on fault variable, I am not getting any option of "Make Object ID"

Comment: sorry, yes, you have to do it from the _Locals_ window. See how here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/03/04/make-objectid-vstipdebug0015.aspx